# VIIRS and image export

Tags: export, image, google

I am trying to export a VIIRS night image, a clipped country but the result is just a black picture. How can I do this?

```
var visualize = {
min: 0.0,
  max: 60.0,
  palette: ['#303030', '#696969', '#808080', '#A9A9A9', '#C0C0C0', '#DCDCDC', '#FFFFFF']
  ['#FFFFFF']
  };
  
Export.image.toDrive({
  image:LightImage.visualize(visualize),
  description: 'LightImage',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  scale: '1000',
  maxPixels: '1000000000',
  fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF',
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Open output in qgis>>>properties>>>symbology

1. change colour gradient from white to black (u can see some black spots if you zoom in) same in the default setting but a bit difficult to observe.
   Else lower the maximum value.
   Or
2. select palette>>>classify>>>apply

U might observe most of the pixels have values far lower than the maximum value.

Another way is properties>>>histogram which will show the distribution of luminosity.
Hope this solves your issue